# How to pass a param from command button to controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I am not sure what is wrong with my code, but I get a null as a value in the controller, once I click the button. I read a lot, and I think I am using the right tags, but still not working.

VF Page:

```
<td>
    <apex:commandButton styleclass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-grow" value="New Contact" action="{!newExistingContactButton}"  reRender="fake">
        <apex:param name="masterId" value="{!result.masterId}" assignTo="{!masterIdRecord}"/>
     </apex:commandButton>                
</td>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class DonorSearchCon {
 public String masterIdRecord {get; set;}

    public pageReference newExistingContactButton(){

        system.debug('masterIdRecord: ' +masterIdRecord);

    string masterId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('masterId');
    system.debug('masterId: ' +masterId);

    for(MergedSearchResult result: advSearchResults){           
       if(result.masterId == masterId){
            System.debug('Result :' +result);
            System.debug('CompanyName: ' +result.companyName);
            System.debug('first Name: ' +result.firstName);
            System.debug('last Name: ' +result.lastName);
            con.FirstName = result.firstName;//result.firstName
            con.LastName = result.lastName;
            System.debug('con.firstname: ' +result.firstName);
            con.Status__c = 'Active';
            System.debug('con2.Status__c: ' +con.Status__c);
            break;
       }
    }

    pageReference newContactRecord = newPageReference('/apex/NewContactGMS?');
    //newContactRecord.setRedirect(true);
    return newContactRecord;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of {!result.masterId}?

Comment: an example would be 12345

Answer (score 0):

[`<apex:param>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm) does not support `<apex:commandButton>`:

> A parameter for the parent component. The  component can only be a child of the following components:
>
> - `<apex:actionFunction>`
> - `<apex:actionSupport>`
> - `<apex:commandLink>`
> - `<apex:outputLink>`
> - `<apex:outputText>`
> - `<flow:interview>`

If you want a button-like appearance, use the `<apex:commandButton>`, but use an `onclick` to call an `<apex:actionFunction>`:

```
<script>
function submit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  submitForm(event.target.dataset.masterId);
}
</script>
<apex:actionFunction action="{!newExistingContactButton}" name="submitForm" reRender="someTarget">
  <apex:param name="masterId" value="" assignTo="{!masterIdRecord}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
<apex:commandButton value="New Contact" onclick="submit(event)" 
    html-data-master-id="{!result.masterId}" />
```

Note the use of an `html-*` pass-through attribute to determine which ID to send to the function.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Actually, not sure if this was related to lightning, but now in my debug statements I am able to get the values. The problem is that my page is not rerouting to the new page. If I leave setRedirect(true), I get rerouted, but my fields on my new page are not autopopulated. Not sure how I can prepopulate the vaues.

Comment: @IvoDimov You'll need to set the appropriate parameters on the PageReference before returning the value. `PageReference newContactRecord = Page.NewContactGMS; newContactRecord.getParams().set('id',masterRecordId); newContactRecord.setRedirect(true); return newContactRecord;`

Comment: Thank you for the info. I updated my code above. I am able to see my debug statement values, based on the passed master id. I am even getting the values in 2 ways. The problem is when I try to reroute to a new page and populate the fields with the values from my controller. They show up as blank.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to fix my problem is by switching from command button to CommandLink instead. It seems like using a command button has its limitations.